# Are they any syntax highlighting plugins that will allow you to embed an ignorable html element into a snippet?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to make dynamic code examples for our api that can be constructed from from input html elements.

A paired down example looks like this, I give the user an input to name the device they would like to create.

`<input class="observable-input" data-key="deviceName" type="text" value="deviceKey" />`

I would then like that input to update code examples (replacing the device name in the example with the one the user inputs).

`<code lang="python">
    device = { "name": "<span data-observeKey="deviceName">Name</span>" }
    client.createDevicewrite(device)
</code>`

I have all of the code setup for observing a change in the input and updating the code examples, this works great. All of the syntax highlighters I have looked at, usually chop the snippet up and rerender the example wrapped with its own html (for styling). Is there an option/configurable way to get a syntax highlighter to not strip the these tags, or is there a different approach I should be looking at for preserving the syntax highlighting and still supporting dynamic updates without having to do a full text search of each snippet's rendered tags.

The example output of the pygment (current syntax highlighter I'm using).

`<li>
    <div class="line">
        <span class="n">device</span>
        <span class="o">=</span>
        <span class="n">{</span>
        <span class="s">"name"</span>
        <span class="p">:</span>
        <span class="s">"Name"</span>
        <span class="n">}</span>
    </div>
</li>`

Comment: You might want to look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/python.html which can handle multiple languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just go with a brute force approach, it ended up being decently performant, ill leave my code here if anyone is interested in what I did

https://gist.github.com/selecsosi/5d41dae843b9dea4888f

Since i use backbone, lodash, and jquery as my base app frameworks the gist uses those. I have a manager which will push updates from inputs to spans on the page which I use to dynamically update the code examples

[image]